# Image transfer from cell to new view controller load wrong images mostly is there any way to fix this problem?

Tags: swift, xcode, imageview, protocols, pass-data

Have a nice weekend. I have a problem about image transfer from cell to new view controller. I am very new in swift and I assume this problem can be solved very easy way but actually I can't find I tried protocols etc. but it can't solved my problem. I have cells with some images and each cell have different image, navigate view controller should show image which is exactly same cell's image. In this point I take image from cell and give a variable name to that image and call view controller and adding equal to this images from image view but it working wrongly. Here my code you will be understand clearly. Sorry for my english.

Here code from cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! itemsCell

    let dataGelen = itemler[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = dataGelen.itemTitleLabel

    if let cellDataImage = dataGelen.itemImageName {
            let url = URL(string: cellDataImage)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.itemsimageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.imageDeneme = UIImage(data: data!)!


                }
                }.resume()
    }
 return cell
 }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let homecon = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    homecon.name = datagelen.itemTitleLabel!
    homecon.imageDenemeHome = imageDeneme
    homecon.showDetailPage()

}
```

and code from view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        self.itemDetailImage.image = imageDetail


}
```

Is there any way to take this image? I didn't use storyboard. I use only code. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageDeneme` contains the image which is assigned in the latest call of `cellForItemAt`. You need to add the image to the data model which caches the image.

Add this property to the class which is represented by `dataGelen`

```
var image : UIImage?
```

and delete `imageDeneme` in the controller.

Then in `cellForItemAt` check if the name **and** the image in the model exists and load it only if the check evaluates to false

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! itemsCell

    let dataGelen = itemler[indexPath.item]
    cell.titleLabel.text = dataGelen.itemTitleLabel
    if let image = dataGelen.image {
        cell.itemsimageView.image = image
    } else if let cellDataImage = dataGelen.itemImageName {
        let url = URL(string: cellDataImage)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, _, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error); return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                cell.itemsimageView.image = image
                self.dataGelen.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    return cell
}
```

In `didSelectItemAt` get the image from the **model**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let homecon = HomeController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    let dataGelen = itemler[indexPath.item]
    homecon.name = dataGelen.itemTitleLabel!
    homecon.imageDenemeHome = dataGelen.image
    homecon.showDetailPage()

}
```